# signalr not working in client in .net mvc

Tags: signalr.client

i using signalr in my .net mvc project
browser log is:

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'notificationhub'.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D'.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:3641/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=DiNre61g3xkbc1m99KZy8uhEaUK3FV0MpD4oiUxvyyser9qZpeA%2BUST3IVuvqQBfLFWc2TwSiy3MieDFXt1VWOcc2XPuL0soOC6kzikEprWOxyCo1AWeFByjXYPntuFC&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=9'.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362

[18:01:35 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000

[18:12:40 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'receiveNotification' on hub 'notificationHub'

what is problem?

Comment: What was expected outcome? Could you append client code?

Answer (score 0):

Client Codes:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {

        $.connection.hub.logging = true; 
        var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
    
          notificationHub.client.receiveNotification = function (message, userID, link) {

            showNotification('new message', message, link);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start(); 
        

    });


    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
    });

</script>




<script type="text/javascript">
        function notify(title,message,link) {
           
            var option = {
                body: message,
                dir: 'rtl',
                title:title,
                icon:'/Content/Images/notification.png',

            }

            var notify = new Notification(title, option);
            

            notify.onclick = function () {
                window.open(link, '_blank');
                notify.close();
            };

            

        }

        function showNotification(title, message, link) {

            if (!("Notification" in window)) {

                
                //alert('Your browser does not support Notification');

            } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

                notify(title, message, link);

            } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {

                Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

                    if (permission === "granted") {

                        notify(title, message, link);

                    }

                });

            }

        }
    </script>
```